# Theorem application

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-geometry

I don't understand how to find the limits for the integral for the area, or what coordinate system to use for the area.

Comment: What two regions does the plane $z=k$ separate from one another? Integrate the divergence of the field over one of those regions to obtain the flux. Be careful about the singularity at the origin.

Comment: The plane separates half-planes, not hemispheres. And yes, the divergence is zero except at the origin, so you are left to just handle the divergence from the origin and then be careful about the sign (the flux is *away* from the origin).